# How to find if my Action<T> is already in list List<Action<T>>

Tags: c#, action

I'm trying to improve my EventAggregator.
I need to check condition before adding it to handlers if its already in the list.
I'm 100% sure i'm adding same callback, but it's always fail.
Any tips?

```
public class CompositePresentationEvent<T> : EventBase //where T : new()
{
    protected List<Action<T>> handlers = new List<Action<T>>();

    public void Subscribe(Action<T> callback)
    {

        bool contains = handlers.Contains(callback); //return false
        var find = handlers.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Target == callback.Target); //return null
        var exists = handlers.Exists(a => a.Target == callback.Target); //return false

        if (contains || find != null || exists)
            return;

        handlers.Add(callback);
    }

    //public void Unsubscribe(string )
    //{
    //    handlers.Remove(a => a);
    //}

    public virtual void Publish(T parameter)
    {
        handlers.ForEach(a => a(parameter));
    }
}
```

Comment: Contains does not work?

Comment: doesnt work, always return false

Comment: How are you creating the `Action<T>` instance? If you're doing `Subscribe(SomeMethod)`, this should work. If you're doing `Subscribe(x => DoSomething(x))`, then you'll get a distinct `Action<T>` instance each time you call `Subscribe`. See here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/anQJ7r

Comment: In general, delegates override `Equals()` to check the target instance and method. As noted above, anonymous methods (in particular, those that capture variables, though in the past this applied to all of them) don't work in this scheme because a new instance of the compiler-generated class is the target instance and you get a new one each time. See duplicate for alternatives to delegate equality that might work for you. Without a [mcve] it's impossible to know what exactly your code's problem, but there's ample Q&A on the site that discuss how delegate equality works to answer this question.

Comment: @canton7 you are right, i'm using it wrong way changed             _aggregator.GetEvent<OnMessageCompleted>().Subscribe(msg => OnMessage(msg)); to _aggregator.GetEvent<OnMessageCompleted>().Subscribe(OnMessage);. I'm still getting same problem, but i think i have some other issue.